# How to raise or emit an event?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, michelson

In Solidity there's `emit` keyword for raising an event. How to do it in Tezos in a smart contract?

Namely, a) define b) emit an event

?

Answer (score 1):

Events will be introduced in the Kathmandu upgrade. See this blog post from Marigold for details:

https://www.marigold.dev/post/how-to-send-events-from-contract-fast

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no standard way to do this but a possible pattern to simulate this is to call a specific contract doing nothing with its parameter; the call to this sink contract is the event.

Comment: How woud calling other contract simulate an event? And is there a plan to add events in the future?